# BITCOIN TO USD API

Tags: api, bitcoin

I want to exchange currency from Bitcoin(Or some other CryptoCurrency) to USD. 
Which API would you recommend if  it exits ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use blockchain.info API:

URL:

https://blockchain.info/ticker

Response:

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 478.68, "last" : 478.68, "buy" : 478.55, "sell" : 478.68,  "symbol" : "$"}
}
```

Details:

> Returns a JSON object with the currency codes as keys. "15m" is the 15
>   minutes delayed market price, "last" is the most recent market price,
>   "symbol" is the currency symbol.

Find more details here:
https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api